# Should I use more than one interrogative pronoun in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I have to say " who came when, where, how"

how should i write it, can I use when/where/how in a single sentence?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you may use multiple interrogative pronouns in a sentence:

> **Who** came to the meeting, **when** and **where** was the meeting was 
>   held, **why** wasn't I informed, and **how** did everyone manage to keep
>   me in the dark?

But the particular wording, type of parallelism, and emphasis all depend on your particular situation, of which we know nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it correct to say?

"Who came? When, where, and how, it is the task of Government to know.

Comment: You've spliced two sentences together, starting with "When."  Whether you could say something close to this depends on the formality of the situation and the audience you're addressing.  Notice that you're not using "when," "where," and "how" as interrogative pronouns, since they're not in a question.

Comment: Then how should I say it? I'm really greatful to you , sir.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in English. It would probably be written:

"Who came? When, where, and how?"

Comment: Yes you could say *When, where, how and why did he come?* But *who* is the odd man out and more difficult to accommodate. I suppose you could say *When, where, why and how did who come?* but I think it would be stretching things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In embedded questions—especially when talking and asking about confusing situations—we can have multiple interrogatives in a single sentence.

> What we have seen in Chinese can also be easily seen to obtain in
> Japanese and English. Take the paradigm (21) in English, for example:
>
> (21)
> a. Who remembers where we bought what?
> b. Who remembers where we
> met who?
> c. *Who remembers what we bought why?
> d. *Who remembers what
> we bought how?
>
> Also the paradigm in (22):
>
> (22)
> a. Who bought what?
> b. Which man pleased which woman?
> c. *Who bought
> the books why?
> d. *Who bought the books how? [*Between Syntax and
> Semantics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Between_Syntax_and_Semantics/Nj6MAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22who%20bought%20what%22&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover)

This rule-bound embedding isn't the typical way we request multiple pieces of information when bringing up a topic, which the OP is asking about. However, it can be used when asking for clarification.

*That was the most convoluted movie plot I've ever seen! Do you know who stole what from whom and why?*

This would require quite a few individual questions to unpack, and the *why* spans all, or at least more than one of the others.

> What objects were stolen?
> Who stole each?
> Who was each object
> stolen from?
> Why did A steal B from C?
> Why did C steal D from A?
> ...